# How to keep text on image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to keep the text on the image slider?
If the plugins is the solution they should not be heavy it should be easy to understand and implement.

Comment: do you know html4,5, css1,2,3, basics of js/jquery and other libraries?

Comment: then do get some time for it, develop something, if you come to any issue post the tried code and certainly you'll get the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add captions under each image using `data-caption`or in a `span` after the image.
You can add larger text using the `title` tag, for example:

```
<div class="MagicSlideshow">
<img src="example1.jpg" data-caption="Descriptive text can go here." title="Title here"/>
<img src="example2.jpg" data-caption="You can have one or two sets of text, or none at all." title="Another title"/>
<img src="example3.jpg" data-caption="You can also use HTML such as<b>bold</b>,<i>italic</i> and<a href='/magicslideshow/'>links</a>."/>
</div>
```

Plz refer this one.

[Demo](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magicslideshow/integration/)

Comment: Dont u have more easy plugin than this?

Comment: Plz refer this one http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h